# French Theoremstyle

Tags: french

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}



\theoremstyle{definition}


\begin{document} 

\end{document}
```

I am working in a French Environment and I am getting the error "Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \theoremstyle
                  {definition}". Most probably Theoremstyle is not defined for the French Environment. How should I write it?

Comment: You need either `amsthm` or `ntheorem`. I usually recommend the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to load the package amsthm, I have attached an example below:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Exemple}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}

\begin{document} 
\begin{theorem}
Mon nouveau théorème
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Et voila
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Then you can fine tune how your environments (theorem, definition, corollary, etc) will behave. I have added a few environments in the code above along with their French names.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: I suppose you want to load `babel` with the `french` option.

Comment: @GuM: No, since version 3.10, language options of babel should be loaded with the document class, so all language-dependent packages be informed.

Comment: @Bernard: You know what?  I didn’t notice the `french` option passed to the document class… :-)

Comment: @GuM: Speed reading? ;o)

Comment: off topic: since`amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, it's not necessary to do that separately.